# How to convert LineString with a preset width to a Polygon?

Tags: geojson, shapely

As per image below, I need to create a Polygon from a LineString that has a preset line width. How do I do this with Shapely or any other methods available?

[image: LineString]

Comment: With a function called "buffer".

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Comment: Buffer is one of the most basic and often use GIS functions and is implemented in about every GIS software. You can do that in very different ways - using code, using graphical interface tools etc. For an easy way to create buffers, use open source QGIS > Menu Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `geom.buffer(distance)` to **buffer** any Shapely geometry.

https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.buffer

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I am a newbie to this GIS so do not know what is the exact way to approach this problem. Thanks!